# The "open popup programmatically" button not working on my mapbox.js map I have created

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, mapbox

I have set up a map using Mapbox.js and I need to open my marker areas with an external button. I have looked through the examples of mapbox.com and found the "[open popup programmatically](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/open-popup-externally/)" option to be best fitting.

However when I plug it in it's not working with my Json Script. I need some help please?

I have provided my [script] to look at below:

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic21vcnJpczMiLCJhIjoiU1RtclNJMCJ9.AWDKQ9l9dY32tB5J8srivg';
var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', 'smorris3.78f0898a', {
        attributionControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        legendControl: {
            position: 'bottomleft'
        }
    })
    .setView([32.888065, -96.964602], 11);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var geoJson = [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-96.964602, 32.888065]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "My Title #1",
            "description": "My Description #1",
            "icon": {
                "iconUrl": "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/RTA/ArX/RTAArXyTL.png",
                "iconSize": [30, 30], // size of the icon
                "iconAnchor": [15, 15], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                "popupAnchor": [0, -15], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                "className": "dot"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-111.858841, 33.436066]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "My Title #2",
            "description": "My Description #2",
            "icon": {
                "iconUrl": "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/RTA/ArX/RTAArXyTL.png",
                "iconSize": [30, 30], // size of the icon
                "iconAnchor": [15, 15], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                "popupAnchor": [0, -15], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                "className": "dot"
            }
        }
    }

];

//==============================================
// map.dragging.disable();
map.touchZoom.disable();
// map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

//==============================================
// Custom Icon
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var custmarker = e.layer,
        features = custmarker.feature;
    custmarker.setIcon(L.icon(features.properties.icon));
});

//==============================================
// Button popup
map.featureLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('open-popup').onclick = clickButton;
});

function clickButton() {
    map.featureLayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {
        if (marker.feature.properties.title === 'My Title #1') {
            marker.openPopup();
        }
    });
}

//==============================================
// Change location of zoom
new L.Control.Zoom({
    position: 'topright'
}).addTo(map);

// Add features to the map.
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);
```

```css
.map-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 425px;
    position: relative;
}

#mapbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.js"></script>


<div class="map-container">
    <div class="map-info" id="mapbox"></div>
</div>

<button id='open-popup' class='ui-control'>open popup</button>
```

Comment: What is not working? What error message(s) are you getting?

Comment: Attempting to get the button in the bottom left (when you run code snippet) to pop up the tool tip menu. I'm just getting no response, no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This part:

```
map.featureLayer.on('ready', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('open-popup').onclick = clickButton;
});
```

never fires because you already have another event:

```
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
```

The onready event is for asynchronous calls. [Reference here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.9/#the-ready-event).

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic21vcnJpczMiLCJhIjoiU1RtclNJMCJ9.AWDKQ9l9dY32tB5J8srivg';
var map = L.mapbox.map('mapbox', 'smorris3.78f0898a', {
        attributionControl: false,
        zoomControl: false,
        legendControl: {
            position: 'bottomleft'
        }
    })
    .setView([32.888065, -96.964602], 11);

var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var geoJson = [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-96.964602, 32.888065]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "My Title #1",
            "description": "My Description #1",
            "icon": {
                "iconUrl": "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/RTA/ArX/RTAArXyTL.png",
                "iconSize": [30, 30], // size of the icon
                "iconAnchor": [15, 15], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                "popupAnchor": [0, -15], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                "className": "dot"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-111.858841, 33.436066]
        },
        "properties": {
            "title": "My Title #2",
            "description": "My Description #2",
            "icon": {
                "iconUrl": "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/RTA/ArX/RTAArXyTL.png",
                "iconSize": [30, 30], // size of the icon
                "iconAnchor": [15, 15], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                "popupAnchor": [0, -15], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                "className": "dot"
            }
        }
    }

];

//==============================================
// map.dragging.disable();
map.touchZoom.disable();
// map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();

//==============================================
// Custom Icon
myLayer.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var custmarker = e.layer,
        features = custmarker.feature;
    custmarker.setIcon(L.icon(features.properties.icon));
  
  document.getElementById('open-popup').onclick = clickButton;
});


//==============================================
// Change location of zoom
new L.Control.Zoom({
    position: 'topright'
}).addTo(map);

// Add features to the map.
myLayer.setGeoJSON(geoJson);

function clickButton() {
    myLayer.eachLayer(function(marker) {console.info(marker);
        if (marker.feature.properties.title === 'My Title #1') {
            marker.openPopup();
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.map-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 425px;
    position: relative;
}

#mapbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.1.9/mapbox.js"></script>


<div class="map-container">
    <div class="map-info" id="mapbox"></div>
</div>

<button id='open-popup' class='ui-control'>open popup</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Friggin' awesome. Great explanation too!